# How to change the size of WPF chart legend

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

I have a WPF chart in the background code and a legendstyle applied to it. How do I reduce the size of the legend; i.e. fontsize etc.

Background code:

```
 ScatterSeries series;


            chart1.Series.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < model.CDFResults.Count; i++)
            {
                series = new ScatterSeries();
                series.DependentValuePath = "Value";
                series.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
                series.ItemsSource = model.CDFResults[i].FinalResult1;
                series.Title = model.CDFResults[i].categoryname;


                Style dataPointStyle = GetNewDataPointStyle(Col,i);
                series.DataPointStyle = dataPointStyle;

                series.LegendItemStyle = (Style)Layout.Resources["LegendItemStyle1"];
                chart1.Series.Add(series);
            }
```

Data point style is set from this function but I don't think it affects the legend :

```
 private static Style GetNewDataPointStyle(List<Color> Col,int i)
    {

        Color background = Col[i];
        Style style = new Style(typeof(DataPoint));
        Setter st1 = new Setter(DataPoint.BackgroundProperty,new SolidColorBrush(background));
        Setter st2 = new Setter(DataPoint.HeightProperty,12.0);
        Setter st3 = new Setter(DataPoint.WidthProperty, 12.0);
        style.Setters.Add(st1);
        style.Setters.Add(st2);
        style.Setters.Add(st3);
        return style;
    }
```

In the XAML, legend style is set this way but I wonder if it is actually being used because when I try to change the Fontsize or Fontstyle, changes are not applied :

```
<Style x:Key="LegendItemStyle1" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LegendItem">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LegendItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Background}" Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Height="2" Margin="0,0,3,0" Width="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontStyle="Italic" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And the charting toolkit in XAML:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="chart1" Background ="White" Title="Cumulative Distributed Function Plot" FontFamily="Tahoma" >

             <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Tahoma" Title="Cumulative Probability"/>

                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Tahoma" />

                </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
```

Here is the screenshot of the legend:

[image]

Comment: Make sure `Layout.Resources["LegendItemStyle1"]` can actually find the correct style.

Comment: Hi @jstreet: Could you please tell me where I am incorrect in the WPF? I am confused!

Comment: Place a break point on this line: `series.LegendItemStyle = (Style)Layout.Resources["LegendItemStyle1"];` and verify that it is actually returning the style you expect.

Comment: Also, `LegendItemStyle1` does not seem to change the font size at all.